# allow php rwx on created dir using mkdir()

Tags: php, linux

When ever my user "apache" creates a directory, I cannot add new files onto it via php upload, i have to change the folder's permissions for it to work.

how do i ensure that when a user uploads a file and a folder is created automatically by php, that file will be added onto that folder after creation, without it giving me a unwrittable folder error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
mkdir($newdirectory);
chmod($newdirectory, 0777);
```